# iOS - Using UIMonthYearPicker with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uipickerview

I need to use third party library called [UIMonthYearPicker](https://github.com/jeksys/UIMonthYearPicker) in my project.

I use the above library in my MKNewpary view controller.
I implemented the UIPickerView in the The .xib of the MKNewparty view controller.

My MKNewpary.h

```
@property(retain,nonautomic)IBOUTLET UImonthYearPicker*picker;
```

How do I make sure this picker uses the UIMonthYearPicker class?

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the instructions on the [GitHub project page,](https://github.com/jeksys/UIMonthYearPicker) you need to change the class of your `UIPickerView` to `UIMonthYearPicker`.  Change the class in Interface Builder by navigating to the Utilities view -> Identity Inspector, and changing Class under Custom Class to `UIMonthYearPicker`.

[image]